# how do i add lines to my pie graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, label, pie-chart

I have a pie graph in mat lab but some of the labels are overlapping and hard to read i am trying to add line to the graph to make it easier to read.

```
subplot(2,2,1)
normal_behavior = [21 56 24];
p = pie(normal_behavior);

pText = findobj(p,'Type','text');
percentValues = get(pText,'String'); 
txt = {'Avoidance of Objects ';'Middle of sidewalk ';'Stops Often '}; 
combinedtxt = strcat(txt,percentValues); 

pText(1).String = combinedtxt(1);
pText(2).String = combinedtxt(2);
pText(3).String = combinedtxt(3);
title("Normal Robot Behvior")

subplot(2,2,2)
unusual_behavior = [2 4 4 33 22 35];
p = pie(unusual_behavior);

pText = findobj(p,'Type','text');
percentValues = get(pText,'String'); 

txt = {'Spoke';'Directional changes ';'Got Stuck '; 'Blocked the Sidewalk ';'Unexpected Awareness ';'No Unusual Behavior '}; 
autopct='%1.1f%%';
pctdistance= 0.5; 
labeldistance=1.1;
combinedtxt = strcat(txt,percentValues); 

pText(4).String = combinedtxt(4);
pText(5).String = combinedtxt(5);
pText(6).String = combinedtxt(6);

line([.5,5,-3],[.5,2,15])
pText(3).String = combinedtxt(3);



title("Unusual Robot Behavior")

subplot(2,2,3)
unusual_reason = [83 3 13];
p = pie(unusual_reason);

pText = findobj(p,'Type','text');
percentValues = get(pText,'String'); 
txt = {'Movement ';'Unexpected location ';'Speech '}; 
combinedtxt = strcat(txt,percentValues); 

pText(1).String = combinedtxt(1);
pText(2).String = combinedtxt(2);
pText(3).String = combinedtxt(3);

title("Reasoning for Unusual Robot Behavior")

subplot(2,2,4)
Delay = [82 18];
p = pie(Delay);

pText = findobj(p,'Type','text');
percentValues = get(pText,'String'); 
txt = {'Yes ';'No '}; 
autopct='%1.1f%%';
pctdistance=0.5; 
labeldistance=1.1;
combinedtxt = strcat(txt,percentValues); 

pText(1).String = combinedtxt(1);
pText(2).String = combinedtxt(2);

title("Order Delays")[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvLJF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvLJF.png)type here
```

I added the line code to try and get lines on the graph but it was not is the right location and did not change the orientation of the label

```
line([.5,5,-3],[.5,2,15])
pText(3).String = combinedtxt(3);
```